# save into a txtfile realtime c++

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have a problem, I have to save into a txt file a lot of data, the problem is that I receive them every 100ns from a serial port.
How can i do? I tried to put data on a RichTextBox but I receive a thread error.
Sorry for my English.

I'm using Windows 7 64bit

```
    private: void FindPorts(void)
    {
        array<Object^>^ ListaPorte = SerialPort::GetPortNames();
        this->cmbPort->Items->AddRange(ListaPorte);
    }

private: System::Void btnOpenPort_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
         {
             if(this->cmbPort->Text==String::Empty || this->cmbBaudRate->Text==String::Empty)
                 this->rtbLog->Text="cmbError";
             else
             {
                 try{
                     if(!this->serialPort->IsOpen)
                     {
                         this->serialPort->PortName = this->cmbPort->Text;
                         this->serialPort->BaudRate = Int32::Parse(this->cmbBaudRate->Text);
                         this->serialPort->Open();
                         this->rtbLog->Text+="Porta aperta\r\n";
                         this->btnOpenPort->Text="Close Port";
                     }
                     else
                     {
                          this->serialPort->Close();
                          this->rtbLog->Text+="Porta chiusa\r\n";
                          this->btnOpenPort->Text="Open Port";
                     }
                 }
                 catch(UnauthorizedAccessException^)
                 {
                    this->rtbLog->Text+="UnauthorizedAccessException\r\n";
                 }
             }
         }

    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
    {
        if(!lettura)
        {
            lettura = true;
            this->button1->Text="sto leggendo";
        }
        else
        if(lettura)
        {
            lettura=false;
            //rtbLog->Text += letturaBuffer;
            this->button1->Text="sono ferma";
        }
        //serialPort->
    }

    private: System::Void serialPort_DataReceived(System::Object^  sender, System::IO::Ports::SerialDataReceivedEventArgs^  e) 
    {
        if(lettura){
            //letturaBuffer += serialPort->ReadExisting() + "\r\n";
            rtbLog->Text += serialPort->ReadExisting() + "\r\n";
        }


    }
```

Comment: Show some code. Describe exactly its behavior and error that you've got... provide more details so that people can understand what you're dealing with.

Comment: What environment is this in?  Operating system?  Are you doing this in a device driver?

Comment: how can you receive data every 100ns from serial port? every 100ns is 10 million a second, and no serial port is capable of a baud rate anywhere close to this. Can you explain a little more what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sure you meant **nanoseconds**, or should this read **microseconds**, or even **milliseconds**?? See also @camelccc's comment ...
If it's milliseconds, it shouldn't be a problem with windoze, just have one thread receiving and buffering the data, and another that updates the display (or textfile saving) asynchronously.

Comment: RS422 can transmit a byte every ~763ns, which is almost 100ns per _bit_.  Maybe that's the misunderstanding?

Comment: @MooingDuck May be. I know pretty well that there are faster serial interfaces. But would such be supported by simply using `SerialPort` class? I'm not so firm doing such stuff using windows environment. The OP should definitely clarify this in his question. AFAIR there aren't any standard windows timing mechanisms that'll directly lead to a ns scaled resolution.

Comment: The point is simple, Mattia Buffa has to tell if he made a typo or not. Because his scenario is perfectly possible.

Answer (score 2):

With a normal OS you wont be able to hold the pace if the data always comes at 100ns interval. 100ns interval is 10MHz so you should look for a realtime OS's that can deal with that speed. To display it in realtime you need lightweight components, so actually you should benchmark that RichTextBox and check if it can handle 10MHz.
Another problem you might have is the interrupt latency, if it takes 1us to get it, you already missed 10 data transfers.

Comment: see camelccc's comment on the question or calculate it yourself taking in account the available baudrates for (standard) serial interfaces. And besides that 'n' layouts quite close to 'm', at least on my keyboard and 'µ' with 'Alt Gr' is also on the 'm' key.

Comment: @g-makulik RS422 goes 10Mbit/s, so if i calculate correctly that is 10MHz or 100 'nano'seconds interval. And to my knowledge that is a standard serial interface only not single-ended like RS232. Oh and there is also RS485 ... That is ofcourse not written on your keyboard.

Comment: 100 ns would be the bit interval, but the byte interval would be 1 us, assuming 8 data bits + start bit + stop bit.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely you're getting data every 100 ns: The maximum speed for a standard serial port is 115,200 bits per second, which is 11,520 bytes per second, maximum. Even if your event is getting signaled for every byte received (also unlikely), that's every 87 microseconds, not every 100 nanoseconds.

The reason you're getting a thread error is because the `serialPort_DataReceived` method is being called on a threadpool thread, and UI components can only be accessed from the UI thread. Let's fix that, then worry about how often you want to do this, and whether it's possible in a non-RTOS.

It looks from your code like you're using WinForms, not WPF. Give this a try:

```
void AddAString(String^ s)
{
    this->rtbLog->Text += (s + Environment::NewLine);
}

void serialPort_DataReceived(Object^ sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs^ e) 
{
    if(lettura)
    {
        this->BeginInvoke(
            gcnew Action<String^>(this, MyClass::AddAString),
            serialPort->ReadExisting());
    }
}
```

Comment: You talk about RS232 and thats not the only serial connection. RS422 goes alot faster and there are also customized serial interfaces... So you're assumption that he's not getting that speed is wrong.

Comment: @fork: RS422 is 763ns per byte tops.

Comment: You're correct, there are ways to go faster over serial. However, I'd say that my assumption *may* be wrong: Without a mention of custom hardware or RS422, I think it's likely that the asker either made a typo or a calculation mistake with the "100 ns". Assuming 100 ns, 8 bits/byte plus a start & stop bit, that's 100 Mbit/sec, which seems unlikely.

Comment: I agree he should have mentioned it in his question. But i had the same problem a while ago, thats why i related and did not think about typo's.

Comment: @fork Can you elaborate your particular situation and if you managed to access this (HW) interface using `SerialPort` class? You have mentioned in your answer that it's at least not possible to use standard windows interfaces, but need to use a different OS.

Comment: @g-makulik at the time i answered he didnt post the code. I mentioned in my answer that you cant have an interface working at those speeds in a standard OS.

Comment: @fork _I mentioned in my answer that you cant have an interface working at those speeds in a standard OS_ which is absolutely right IMHO!

Comment: BTW it can be achieved with a standard linux kernel by adapting the [Jiffy Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiffy_%28time%29) to the HW capabilities. No 'real time' OS needed, whatever this means ...

Comment: sounds interesting and how do you adjust the Jiffy Time in Linux for example? Because if i could do that it would solve alot of problems for me. So basically what you say is that you can adjust the interrupt frequency? Up to how fast with a normal OS? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system

Comment: @fork The term 'Real Time' depends if you really need to have exactly timed events at a certain precision (which involves time aware protocol solutions), or reacting to events within a certain time window. That's broadly confused ...
There are linux kernel implementations that allow to tune the jiffy time (AFAIR the standard is s.th. about 100ms) and have all coponents/drivers adapted not to make assumptions on the standard Jiffy Time. May be commercial implementations though ...

Comment: @fork This might help: [Real-Time Linux Wiki](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page). Personally I only have experience with FreeRTOS ports. Standard linux kernel capabilities were usually sufficient otherwise ...